# nodejs crypto aes decoded result truncated

Tags: node.js, aes, cryptojs

Please help, I can't figure out why NodeJS Crypto AES decoded result below become truncated,
where is the mistake?

```
let aesKey = Buffer.from('41e7a9ffb80d49651e5068d3b78ce3e40b9129a12f359b0e7232466caba4babd', 'hex')
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ecb', aesKey, '')
let encoded = cipher.update(Buffer.from('b9ec7407162374b9e3bb02f3f693d1ea3cbdfde0cdc3bb24890d5cc00fc09ffc', 'hex'))

// its return correct result bd453040b52525760298dd118f6861720926d70f83432023bb9cd4ef35ca4a5b
console.log("encodedHex:" + encoded.toString('hex'))

let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ecb', aesKey, '');
let decoded = decipher.update(Buffer.from('bd453040b52525760298dd118f6861720926d70f83432023bb9cd4ef35ca4a5b','hex'));

// it should be b9ec7407162374b9e3bb02f3f693d1ea3cbdfde0cdc3bb24890d5cc00fc09ffc, but truncated to b9ec7407162374b9e3bb02f3f693d1ea
console.log("decodedHex:" + decoded.toString('hex'))
```

Comment: For both encryption and decryption, the `update()` call must be followed by a `final()` call, s. the crypto documentation. The `final()` calls are missing in your code. The data of the `update()` and `final()` call must be concatenated, e.g. using `Buffer.concat([...,...])` (since you store ciphertext and decrypted data in a buffer).

Comment: Solved, I missing final() and setAutoPadding(false)

Comment: The fixed code works also if padding is enabled (enabled padding is even the normal case). However, for a block cipher like ECB, padding can be disabled if the length of the plaintext is an integer multiple of the block size. If the length criterion is not met, padding *must* be enabled.